# Окно приложения поверх окон других приложений (включая игры)

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui

Как можно отображать gui окно PyQt5 поверх игр?

Пробовал `setWindowFlag(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)`, но работает только на приложениях, поверх игр не отображается.

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему и лучше расскажите что вы хотите сделать.

Answer (score 0):

Если под Windows, то надо сделать что-то типа такого (поверх игр не проверял)

```
import win32gui

def __init__(...):
    ...
    # вызов системной функции Windows
    win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(self.winId())

    flags = self.windowFlags()
    self.setWindowFlags(flags | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint )
    ...
```

Comment: Не работает в играх.